# Finding the GradCam heatmap for a Transfer Learning based model

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, heatmap

I took a pretrained Xception model as my base, added some more Dense layers for classification and then trained it on my custom dataset. Here is the model summary:
`print(model.summary())`
Model: "sequential"

---

Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

---

xception (Functional)       (None, 4, 4, 2048)        20861480

flatten (Flatten)           (None, 32768)             0

dropout (Dropout)           (None, 32768)             0

dense (Dense)               (None, 512)               16777728

dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 1026

=================================================================
Total params: 37,640,234
Trainable params: 37,585,706
Non-trainable params: 54,528

---

None

Here is what I had tried:

```
img_array = keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(get_img_array(img_path, size=IMAGE_SIZE))
print(model.predict(img_array))
```

`[[0.1292125 0.8707875]]`

Main calling function:

```
last_conv_layer_name = "block14_sepconv2_act"

# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap, preds = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, last_conv_layer_name)
# preds = np.array(preds)
print("Predicted:", preds)

# Display heatmap
plt.matshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

```
def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    
    grad_model = keras.models.Model(inputs = [model.inputs], outputs = [model.get_layer('xception').get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output])
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
        
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
            print(pred_index)
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    print(tape)
    print("----------------------")
    print("Class channel: ",class_channel)
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy(), preds
```

I keep getting a Graph disconnected ValueError at the 1st line of the `make_gradcam_heatmap` function, during grad_model creation:
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

I cannot use `model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output` directly since that layer is a sub-part of the 'xception' layer of the model.
Could someone help me with this?